# C# Picturebox draw random circle

Tags: c#

I would like to draw a circle at a random position in a `PictureBox`

I tried to do it with the following code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int width = random.Next(0, 400);
    int height = random.Next(0, 400);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, width, height, 25, 25);
}
```

This however results in the circle "jumping" around in the `PixtureBox`.
I'm confused as to why this is.

I would like to determine the position once at the beginning of my Program and draw it at that position constantly.

Answer (score 0):

crate a variable of the random numbers upon program load and use those values when you paint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    int cwidth = new Random().Next(0, 400);
    int cheight = new Random().Next(0, 400);

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, cwidth, cheight, 25, 25);
    }
```

Comment: Nice touch, adding the c prefix to the (now gloabal) variables. They still don't describe the elipses width and height though...

Comment: Intended shape is a circle, not ellipse.

Comment: A circle is just a special case of an ellipse.

Comment: Can you represent an ellipse with just cwidth, cheight, and a fixed 25 for both axes? Also read the title...

Comment: Do not create multiple Random objects in quick succession!

Comment: The point is. You and OP call their variables width and height but pass them to the Draw method as *position*

Comment: Naming was his decision. I tried to make as little changes as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding as to when the `pictureBox1_Paint` method is called.

In fact it is called every time the `PictureBox` needs to be painted. This can occur on a number of occasions such as:

- Resizing the PictureBox and/or the Parent Control.
- Losing/Gaining focus on the Parent Control.
- A call to `PictureBox.Invalidate()`

Depending on circumstances it may be called many times **per scond**.

The way your code is structured, the position for the circle will be recalculated each time the `Paint` method is called.

You should think about a way to calculate the position once and reuse those positions in the Paint method.

For example:

```
public class MyForm {
    // A global variable to hold the position 
    private Rectangle _circleShape;

    // You can create this method via the Designer by
    //  double-clicking on the Form
    public void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int x = random.Next(0, 400);
        int y = random.Next(0, 400);
        int width = 25; // fixed width
        int height = 25; //  and height

        // Assign the result to your "global" variable
        _circleShape = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        // Only do the actual "drawing" in this method
        e.Graphics.FillElipse(Brushes.Red, _circleShape);
    }
```